# invite.uses returning None

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to figure out who invited a user when they join, but when I try to get the number of times an invite has been used I keep getting `None`. Here's my code:

```
 @client.event
    async def on_ready(self):
        global before_invites
        before_invites = []
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            for invite in await guild.invites():
                invite = await self.client.get_invite(invite)
                x = [invite.url, invite.uses, invite.inviter.id]
                before_invites.append(x)
            print(before_invites)
```

which then prints out `[['http://discord.gg/xxxxxxx', None, 01234567890123456789], ['http://discord.gg/xxxxxxx', None, 01234567890123456789], ...]`

So far I've double checked and the bot has all permissions in the server and made sure that there are invites for the server that have been used. Can only self accounts see invite uses?

Comment: I don’t believe that should be happening, perhaps it’s a bug. Imo you should raise a bug report in github, since there aren’t much we can do here in SO.

Comment: [`discord.http.invites_from_channel`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/discord/http.py#L655) calls the [`Get Channel Invites`](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-invites) endpoint, which should return the data and metadata of the invites.  Are any of the other fields from the [invite metadata object](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/invite#invite-metadata-object) coming through?

Comment: I also get None for `max_age`, `created_at`, and `max_uses`. I'll go open a report right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `get_invite` instead of using the `Invite` from `Guild.invites`.  `get_invite` uses the [`GET Invite`](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/invite#get-invite) endpoint of the Discord API, which only returns the invite object, not including it's metadata.  By contrast, `Guild.invites` uses the [`GET Channel Invites`](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-invites) endpoint, which does return the metadata objects.

Just use the invites from `Guild.invites` directly:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(self):
    global before_invites
    before_invites = []
    for guild in self.client.guilds:
        for invite in await guild.invites():
            x = [invite.url, invite.uses, invite.inviter.id]
            before_invites.append(x)
        print(before_invites)
```